# Instantiating class with internal constructor at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I've got a class in namespace `Foobar` called `Giggles`. And another class in the same namespace called `Monkey`. They're both in the same assembly.

`Monkey` looks like this:

```
namespace Foobar {
    public class Monkey {
        internal Monkey () { }
        ...
```

That is the only constructor `Monkey` has and I cannot change its source code.

Now, from within a method in `Giggles`, I want to instantiate a `Monkey` using a string containing its class name.

This does not work:

```
var className = "Foobar.Monkey";
var monkley = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(className);
```

Gives this exception message: `"Constructor on type 'Foobar.Monkey' not found."` with of exception type `System.MissingMethodException`.

Any ideas?

Comment: whats wrong with `new Monkey()`?

Comment: I'm creating a `Monkey` from a string whose value is its class name.

Comment: if you need `Monkey` in one or a few specific assemblies, you can use [InternalsVisibleTo](http://geekswithblogs.net/jwhitehorn/archive/2007/11/09/116750.aspx)

Comment: I can't remember exactly the exact syntax but the two part name is something different than a .

Comment: Use `Activator.CreateInstance` with `BindingFlags.NonPublic`

Comment: As Sriram says, if you use the right `BindingFlags`, you'll find the constructor. That said, if the constructor is `internal`, it's usually for a reason, with the author of the class intending you to obtain instances via some other mechanism. If it's truly legitimate for your code to construct the instance directly, then the other assembly should use `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to make the `internal` constructor visible to your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to use [Type.GetConstructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h70wxday(v=vs.110).aspx) with appropriate binding flags

```
/* bindings are: non public and instance to find an internal ctor */
ConstructorInfo monkeyCtor = typeof(Monkey).GetConstructors
            (BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)[0];

/* actual invokation of constructor*/
Monkey monkeyInstance = (Monkey ) monkeyCtor.Invoke(...);
```

This should work for you.